# Why am I seeing this error in while importing CSV file in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import csv file using pandas in Jupyter notebook but I am getting Name not define error. I tried changing the root directory and paths but nothing worked so I am posting it here.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("bankloan.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.head()
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in 
----> 1 df.head()

NameError: name 'df' is not defined

[image]

Comment: Pls, post the code where the error happened and the stack trace of error, so that someone can help.

Comment: You never run the first few cells in your notebook, so `df` i never defined. Note, `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` is unecessary.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you only running the last cell

```
 df.head()
```

You have to run entire notebook first. There should be a number in each of the bracket pair [] next to the cell.

To run entire notebook,  click on the '>>' button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

And re-run all the lines in the notebook.

Comment: While that line is pointless, it won't fix the error, since the previous line is never run, and that is fundamentally the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you give `pd.read_csv(...)` the return object is of type dataframe. You need not explictly convert it into dataframe.

---

So you can safely remove `df = pd.DataFrame(df)`. You have to run entire notebook which could be a reason also.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running only the last cell, while previous cells were never run. in order to use previous cells data in jupyter notebook you need to run previous cells at least once while starting a new kernel.

**step 1 :** import pandas as pd *//run this cell*

**step 2 :** df = pd.read_csv("bankloan.csv") *//now you must run this cell before using "df" anywhere in the notebook in current kernel.*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes. This was the mistake :) Thank you so much